# separate environment config elastic beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm creating a rails app with both web and worker tier in elastic beanstalk.

It's normal to start up web environment with ELB settings inside ebextensions. But I cannot startup worker environment because it doesn't have ELB.

Is there any way to separate ebextensions for each environments without creating another branch for this?

Answer (score -1):

Refer to this link second answer

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=685803

Comment: No information provided, and the link no longer works