# elasticbeanstalk failed to deploy worker environment /var/pids/web.pid: no such file or directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am struggling with EBS for what I figured has a relatively simple architecture. I have a Django app. This Django app will contain code for both my worker environment and my WebServer.I have been deploying to a WebServer just fine, and only have this issue with my Worker environment as I try and incorporate it. [This poor chap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42435032/separate-environment-config-elastic-beanstalk) had the same issue, [which the community](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=685803) doesn't seem to have a good answer for.

This was mistake number 1 I learned, due to not having a great way to separate configurations.

It began with me getting this error:

> 2020/09/03 20:17:59.065285 [ERROR] update processes [web sqsd nginx healthd cfn-hup] pid symlinks failed with error Read pid source file /var/pids/web.pid failed with error:open /var/pids/web.pid: no such file or directory

which from [this link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=326968), I thought was due to my having my `.platform` with an nginx overwrite (only modifying gzip to turn it on) was somehow causing this. I had removed it and redeployed and the error wasn't there, so it seemed logical. Unfortunately it seems rather temperamental, because it's come back (after I have already deployed a few times!!!!).

My first attempt to fix this was using `saved_configs/`

```
├── .elasticbeanstalk
│   ├── config.yml
│   └── saved_configs
│       ├── web.cfg.yml
│       └── worker.cfg.yml
```

and calling it like this:

```
eb create testweb --cfg web
eb create testwrkr -t worker --cfg worker
eb deploy testweb
eb deploy testwrkr
```

which seemed to work, but I still couldn't deploy my worker environment. Next I tried to create a Makefile since removing the .platform fixed the error for me yesterday.

```
ENVS = 'production development'
ifndef env
$(error "env" is not specified. Please use one of: $(ENVS))
endif

create_web: clean copy_web_configuration
    @echo "Creating Environment: $(env)"
    -eb create $(env)

create_worker: clean copy_worker_configuration
    @echo "Creating Worker Environment: $(env)"
    -eb create $(env) -t worker

deploy_web: clean copy_web_configuration
    @echo "Deploying to: $(env)"
    -eb deploy $(env) $(args)
    @$(MAKE) clean

deploy_worker: clean copy_worker_configuration
    @echo "Deploying worker to: $(env)"
    -eb deploy $(env) $(args)
    @$(MAKE) clean

copy_web_configuration:
    @cp -r config/ebs/extensions/shared/ .ebextensions/
    @cp -r config/ebs/extensions/web/ .ebextensions/
    @cp -r config/ebs/platform/web/ .platform/

copy_worker_configuration:
    @cp -r config/ebs/extensions/shared/ .ebextensions/
    @cp -r config/ebs/extensions/worker/ .ebextensions/

clean:
    @find .ebextensions/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec rm -f {} \;
    @rm -rf .platform/nginx
    @find .platform/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec rm -f {} \;
```

so I could be 100% sure that whatever was in `.ebextensions/` or `.platform/` was for the intended platform.

```
My new file tree looks like this:
.ebextensions/
.platform/
config/
├── __init__.py
├── ebs
│   ├── extensions
│   │   ├── shared
│   │   │   ├── 01_packages.config
│   │   │   ├── appslog.config
│   │   │   └── django.config
│   │   ├── web
│   │   │   ├── db-migrate.config
│   │   │   ├── securelistener-clb.config
│   │   │   └── static.config
│   │   └── worker
│   │       └── worker.config
│   └── platform
│       └── web
│           └── nginx
│               └── nginx.conf
├── settings
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── base.py
│   ├── local.py
│   └── production.py
├── urls.py
└── wsgi.py
```

And now, when I deploy (after adding in `cron.yaml`), I get my old friend again

> 2020/09/04 22:12:21.485660 [INFO] Executing instruction: Track pids in healthd
> 2020/09/04 22:12:21.485677 [INFO] This is an enhanced health env...
> 2020/09/04 22:12:21.485697 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p ConsistsOf aws-eb.target | cut -d= -f2
> 2020/09/04 22:12:21.491871 [INFO] nginx.service healthd.service cfn-hup.service sqsd.service
>
> 2020/09/04 22:12:21.491894 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p ConsistsOf eb-app.target | cut -d= -f2
> 2020/09/04 22:12:21.496690 [INFO] web.service
>
> 2020/09/04 22:12:21.496761 [ERROR] update processes [web nginx healthd cfn-hup sqsd] pid symlinks failed with error Read pid source file /var/pids/web.pid failed with error:open /var/pids/web.pid: no such file or directory
> 2020/09/04 22:12:21.496772 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Track pids in healthd]. Stop running the command. Error: update processes [web nginx healthd cfn-hup sqsd] pid symlinks failed with error Read pid source file /var/pids/web.pid failed with error:open /var/pids/web.pid: no such file or directory
>
> 2020/09/04 22:12:21.496776 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
> 2020/09/04 22:12:21.496861 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment successfully generated a 'Procfile'.","timestamp":1599257531,"severity":"INFO"},{"msg":"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1599257541,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}

My worker configuration doesn't have much in it, so I'm at a loss for words on why this won't deploy. Has anyone seen this issue before?
The only resources I have found online are:

- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=955011&#955011 (no answer available)
- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=326968

---

I monitored the logs at the same time and saw in an order of operations that first I get this error:

```
Sep  4 22:42:18 ip-172-31-7-235 web: File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
Sep  4 22:42:18 ip-172-31-7-235 web: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
Sep  4 22:42:18 ip-172-31-7-235 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
Sep  4 22:42:18 ip-172-31-7-235 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
Sep  4 22:42:18 ip-172-31-7-235 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Sep  4 22:42:18 ip-172-31-7-235 web: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'
Sep  4 22:42:18 ip-172-31-7-235 web: [2020-09-04 22:42:18 +0000] [9303] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9303)
Sep  4 22:42:18 ip-172-31-7-235 web: [2020-09-04 22:42:18 +0000] [9296] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
Sep  4 22:42:18 ip-172-31-7-235 web: [2020-09-04 22:42:18 +0000] [9296] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

and then

```
2020/09/04 22:42:21.717799 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p ConsistsOf eb-app.target | cut -d= -f2
2020/09/04 22:42:21.722604 [INFO] web.service

2020/09/04 22:42:21.722678 [ERROR] update processes [web healthd nginx sqsd cfn-hup] pid symlinks failed with error Read pid source file /var/pids/web.pid failed with error:open /var/pids/web.pid: no such file or directory
2020/09/04 22:42:21.722689 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Track pids in healthd]. Stop running the command. Error: update processes [web healthd nginx sqsd cfn-hup] pid symlinks failed with error Read pid source file /var/pids/web.pid failed with error:open /var/pids/web.pid: no such file or directory 

2020/09/04 22:42:21.722694 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2020/09/04 22:42:21.722778 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment successfully generated a 'Procfile'.","timestamp":1599259331,"severity":"INFO"},{"msg":"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1599259341,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}
```

so I'm guessing the `web.service` that isn't being found is because the `ModuleNotFound` error. What I don't understand is I am using the exact same code repo as the Web environment.. so how could the Worker environment fail? The configuration looks okay to me. My tree is above, and the relevant beanstalk configuration is this:

```
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: config.wsgi:application
```

Comment: What is the entry point for the application? It should be called `application`. For example, in flask as show [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html#python-flask-create-app) entry point is `application = Flask(__name__)`. So I think your worker environment also expects `application` variable in your main file. It can't find it, thus you get error about `No module named 'application'`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The variable is called `application` located in `config/wsgi.py` so it seems like my `WSGIPath` should be okay. I've also been deploying that configuration + code base to a web environment just fine for weeks so it was a surprise for me to see that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the original question was about the `web.service` failure, I'll add this note from the AWS support staff.

> Next, ‘web.service’ is the linux service for Beanstalk which is responsible of activating the virtual environment in staging and running the WSGI server using ‘gunicorn’ python plugin[2].  So, from the  error ‘/var/pids/web.pid failed with error:open /var/pids/web.pid’ it looks like, when ‘web.service’ was trying  to run the application using ‘ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 --workers=1 --threads=15 application”’ and it failed as module was missing.

This points to where I thought the issue was, which was the `ModuleNotFound`. When I `tail -f`'d two different log files and saw the `ModuleNotFound` was happening directly before the other error, which supported that thesis.

This ended up happening because after I switched to using a Makefile, I wasn't automatically committing my code before I ran my eb deploy, or at least staging it and running deploy with the `--staged` flag. Unfortunately the recommended advice from AWS was to use two different branches to manage worker code and web code if I want to use the same repository. I found this to be absolutely terrible advice and poor design on EBS, so I decided I will keep my `Makefile`, and found a workaround where if I specify an `.ebignore`, I can circumvent `git`, and whatever files are copied over directly before being deployed, and subsequently cleaned, will be deployed.

---

Here was my debugging process if anyone finds it helpful:

The WSGI application is not launching. This means that the entry point to the python application is not being found for whatever reason.

At the Root of the application, I have:

```
config/
├── settings
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── base.py
│   ├── local.py
│   └── production.py
├── urls.py
└── wsgi.py
```

which has the variable:

```py
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

The configuration file is failing to find this variable for some reason which starts the python application

Relevant Elastic Beanstalk code to start the application in `/.ebextensions/django.config`

```yaml
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: config.wsgi:application
```

This seems right to me, so I'm a bit confused. Also, I've deployed many times with this setup and it's worked; however now it is failing. Why?

*checking the console to see if WSGI path is being set as I think it is*

[image]

It just says application. What does it say on the environments that are actually working? As I thought, the working environment says `config.wsgi:application`. So.. the issue is that /the configuration is not actually making it to Elastic Beanstalk for whatever reason./

*I realized that the files I wanted to deploy were not actually being committed*. The files in the `.ebextensions` directory need to be committed just like the rest of the application. This makes the `Makefile` a little tricky, since the files won't be committed as I've just copied them over.

Trying to add the newly copied files to `git`, then run my deploy with `--staged`, then remove the changes with `git restore --source=HEAD --staged --worktree -- .ebextensions/`. *so I went to look if there is a way to deploy outside of git*. This works but I don't like interfering with the git workflow. From this AWS [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=625778) it looks like this can be accomplished with a `.ebignore` file.

*Specifically said here in the documentation:*
[Configure the EB CLI - AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-ebignore)

> When .ebignore is present, the EB CLI doesn't use git commands to create your source bundle. This means that EB CLI ignores files specified in .ebignore, and includes all other files. In particular, it includes uncommitted source files.

This appears to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same error messages showing up in my logs during `eb deploy`, but for a different reason. Adding in case anyone comes across this in the future

**Short Answer:**

I was storing some vars in Django settings in environment variables. I was *not* creating these environment variables during environment creation. My process was to run `eb create -t worker -p "Python 3.7"` in eb cli. Then let the cli create the env and deploy the code. Deploy would fail with this error message showing in the logs. Setting the env variables during environment creation got this working for me.

**Additional Information:**

My Django worker env and web env are using the same codebase. Both deployed to AWS via EB running on Python 3.6 on Amazon Linux/2.9.15.

I had to upgrade my worker to Python 3.7 on Amazon Linux 2/3.1.3.

When I created the new worker env via eb cli, I did NOT create the environment with environment variables. My typical workflow (that worked fine for me with Amazon Linux/2.9.15) was to create the env via eb cli. Let it create, deploy the code. And then go into the eb web interface and add env variables through configuration.

But on 3.7 on Amazon Linux 2/3.1.3, it seems that env variables need to be set on creation. As I was seeing this exact error message until I created the env with env variables off the bat.

AWS provides a [few ways to do this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-configuration-methods-during.html), but I did it inside of: /.ebextensions/environmentvariables.config

Format of that file is (as an example):

```
option_settings:
  - option_name: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
    value: example.settings
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your process environment definitions first. Empty or undefined variables may cause this exception.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).